# where are route guards in the DI hierarchy?

Tags: angular

Which injectors/providers are available to route guards?

For instance: can a route guard use a service which is only provided for a component?

It seems to me that only module-level providers are accessible to route guards but I can't confirm from the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In **Angular2.0** every is wrapped within the **Module**. **Service** should be injected at **AppModule level** (means within **@NgModule decorator**) or **featureModule level** or **SharedModule level**.

So you have to make sure you inject it somewhere in @NgModule decorator. Then according to scope of that **NgModule**, you'll be able to use your **service** eg. in **canActivate**.

Comment: The one who has downvoted this, can I have an explanation? can you show me other (best) way to use it?

Comment: so you're saying that route guards must have service providers at the module level?

Comment: Yes if you want to use service anywhere, it has to be injected at Module lev as said in answer...